# Is It Possible To Programmatically Clean This Data Using Python?

Tags: python, sql, excel

I'm looking for a quicker way to clean the data in a decent sized spreadsheet (between 5-15k rows) the issue I keep running into is that the data is in such poor shape its taking me ages to actually clean it using just Excel/SQL. To be honest I don't know much about python but I am really interested in learning to help me make my job easier.

This is an example of the data that I would need to clean. Even if it got me 50% of the way there it would save me hours.

```
| Place | Address | City | State | Zip |

|Burger King Hartford, CT | 123 Apple St W|--|--|--|        
|McDonald's| 5 Big Mac dr | New York, NY 10001|--|--|       
|Arby's|--| Sturgis, KY |--|--|         
|Taco Bell|--| Grand Rapids MI 49501 |--|--|        
|Jimmy Johns|--| Fort Wayne, IN. 46774 |--|--|
```

I've thought about two different approaches to this issue but I'm not sure if either of them are possible. If you think either of them are possible or if you have an idea that would work better I'd be very grateful.

My first thought would be to search each string in the dataframe for a specific substring which would be a list of all the state abbreviations (MI, IN, KY etc). If one of those substrings is found then move to the state column. The same would be done for the zip codes but being that there are 47,000 or so of them I don't know how easy that would be.

My second thought is using the split() function in python and split the columns first by the , delimiter which would leave me something like this

```
| Place | Address | City | State | Zip |

|Burger King Hartford  | 123 Apple St W|--|CT|--|       
|McDonald's| 5 Big Mac dr | New York |NY 10001|--|      
|Arby's|--| Sturgis |KY|--|         
|Taco Bell|--| Grand Rapids MI 49501 |--|--|        
|Jimmy Johns|--| Fort Wayne |IN. 46774|--|
```

And then using the split function again to split on the empty space in the newly filled state field. This would not help me with the Grand Rapids MI 49015 because its only delimited by spaces and grand and rapids would be split as well but it would get me pretty close to perfect.

Any suggestions on functions i should read up on or thoughts of how to approach this differently?

Comment: Parsing address data is NASTY business for even an expert. Your approach sounds like a good step and may get you like 80-90% of the way there. It's the remaining 10% that will bring you to tears. That being said, I would definitely choose Python and it's tooling and endless number of modules over excel formulas, sql and prayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions for cleaning up this spreadsheet data in Python:

Load the data into a Pandas dataframe. This will make it easier to manipulate and process the data.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # or whatever source
```

Use string methods like Series.str.extract() to pull out state abbreviations and zip codes into new columns:

```
df['State'] = df['Address'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2})')
df['Zip'] = df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})')
```

Use Series.str.split() to split the Address column on commas. Then take the second element to extract the city name:

```
df['City'] = df['Address'].str.split(',').str[1]
```

Clean up `Place` names by removing extra text with Series.str.replace():

```
df['Place'] = df['Place'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z\s]+', '')
```

Fill missing values and trim extra whitespace with Series.fillna() and Series.str.strip():

```
df = df.fillna('').applymap(str.strip)
```

You can use regex when you want to cleanup using string methods

Answer (score 0):

with your sample data I was able to somewhat normalize it to this `list`:

```
[['Burger King Hartford', '123 Apple St W', '--', 'CT', '--'],
 ["McDonald's", '5 Big Mac dr', 'New York', 'NY', '10001'],
 ["McDonald's", '5 Big Mac dr', 'New York', 'NY', '10001'],
 ["Arby's", '--', 'Sturgis', 'KY', '--'],
 ['Taco Bell', '--', 'Grand Rapids', 'MI', '49501'],
 ['Taco Bell', '--', 'Grand Rapids', 'MI', '49501'],
 ['Jimmy Johns', '--', 'Fort Wayne', 'IN', '46774'],
 ['Jimmy Johns', '--', 'Fort Wayne', 'IN', '46774']]
```

code:

```py
import io, pprint

csv_file = """\
| Place | Address | City | State | Zip |
|Burger King Hartford, CT | 123 Apple St W|--|--|--|
|McDonald's| 5 Big Mac dr | New York, NY 10001|--|--|
|McDonald's| 5 Big Mac dr | New York, NY|--|10001|
|Arby's|--| Sturgis, KY |--|--|
|Taco Bell|--| Grand Rapids MI 49501 |--|--|
|Taco Bell|--| Grand Rapids | MI 49501 |--|
|Jimmy Johns|--| Fort Wayne, IN. 46774 |--|--|
|Jimmy Johns|--| Fort Wayne | IN | 46774 |"""

states = [ 'AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA',
           'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME',
           'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
           'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX',
           'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY']

with io.StringIO(csv_file) as file:
    parsed_data = []
    headers = file.readline() # skip headers
    for line in file:
        remainder = ''
        place, address, city, state, zipcode = \
            line.replace('.', '').replace(',', '').strip('\n|').split('|')
        if state == '--':
            for i in states:
                if   i in place:
                    place, state, remainder = place.partition(i)
                    break
                elif i in address:
                    address, state, remainder = address.partition(i)
                    break
                elif i in city:
                    city, state, remainder = city.partition(i)
                    break
            if zipcode == '--' and remainder.strip(): zipcode = remainder
        else:
            try: state, zipcode = state.split()
            except ValueError: pass
        row = list(map(str.strip, (place, address, city, state, zipcode)))
        parsed_data.append(row)

pprint.pp(parsed_data)
```